# Tweepy API Failing For Every ID

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm running the below code that was given to me by an instructor to grab the status based off the tweet_id in another dataframe I've imported already. When running the code, everything comes back Failed. I don't receive any errors so I'm not sure what I'm missing. When I requested my twitter developer access I didn't have to answer a ton of questions like I've seen other people say they've had to do, so I'm curious if it's just not enough access?

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json
from timeit import default_timer as timer

# Query Twitter API for each tweet in the Twitter archive and save JSON in a text file
# These are hidden to comply with Twitter's API terms and conditions
consumer_key = 'HIDDEN'
consumer_secret = 'HIDDEN'
access_token = 'HIDDEN'
access_secret = 'HIDDEN'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# NOTE TO STUDENT WITH MOBILE VERIFICATION ISSUES:
# df_1 is a DataFrame with the twitter_archive_enhanced.csv file. You may have to
# change line 17 to match the name of your DataFrame with twitter_archive_enhanced.csv
# NOTE TO REVIEWER: this student had mobile verification issues so the following
# Twitter API code was sent to this student from a Udacity instructor
# Tweet IDs for which to gather additional data via Twitter's API
tweet_ids = twitter_archive.tweet_id.values
len(tweet_ids)

# Query Twitter's API for JSON data for each tweet ID in the Twitter archive
count = 0
fails_dict = {}
start = timer()
# Save each tweet's returned JSON as a new line in a .txt file
with open('tweet_json.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    # This loop will likely take 20-30 minutes to run because of Twitter's rate limit
    for tweet_id in tweet_ids:
        count += 1
        print(str(count) + ": " + str(tweet_id))
        try:
            tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id, tweet_mode='extended')
            print("Success")
            json.dump(tweet._json, outfile)
            outfile.write('\n')
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print("Fail")
            fails_dict[tweet_id] = e
            pass
end = timer()
print(end - start)
print(fails_dict)
```

Comment: What is your access level to the Twitter API? Essential or elevated?

Comment: per the above clarifying question - this code will only work if you have access to the legacy v1.1 API, which requires Elevated access. If you have Essential access, you will need to modify the code to use Twitter API v2 via `tweepy.Client` and the [`api.get_tweet`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_tweet) method (with any fields and expansions to specify the data that you require)